# Portion of UITableView does not respond to touch / any events

Tags: ios, uitableview

This problem is a bit hard to convey with code so I'm going to best describe it and maybe someone can guess the issue.

I have a UITableView which has been rotated 90 degrees, effectively making it a horizontal table view. Each cell contains a part of a graph, as seen here:

[image]

This works really well for my needs and allows us to use some of the power of UITableView, particularly cell re-use.

On the iPhone<5, everything worked really well because the UITableView was square (320x320) so it was easy to rotate and modify the frame.

However, I just started adding iPhone 5 support which meant extending the width (and ultimately height after rotation) to be around 320+88. This can be seen in the screenshot above. I found it quite hacky/tricky to get the bounds/centre correct after rotating the table. And maybe this is a problem resulting from it.

The problem (finally!) is that now (on the iPhone5), the bottom 30ish points can't be selected (around the month selection portion). UIButton presses aren't registered on the months, didSelectCell isn't registered on the cell, and it's not possible to swipe across.

- The UITableViewCell frame size is correct. I've set the background color of the UITableViewCell and confirmed that these 30ish points are within the frame.
- There are no subviews or anything else infront of this portion of the table.
- Everything works perfectly on iPhone<5

Any ideas? I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out that I'm pretty much resigned to replacing my implementation with a third-party "HorizontalTable" or a self written ScrollView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresponsive screen on iPhone 5, iOS 6 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547047/unresponsive-screen-on-iphone-5-ios-6-simulator)

Comment: Nope. Good suggestion though. A parent view is receiving responses.

Comment: Ah, I think this may be a different problem: Are you setting the transform on the table view? I've experienced a bug with cell-sizing when you do this - UITableView seems to use its frame width rather than bounds width to decide how wide (tall) to make cells. Stick the table view in a container and set the transform on the container.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I set the background color of the contentView in the willDisplayCell call and it was the correct size. I also tried your suggestion and transformed a container view. Same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after countless wasted hours, it does indeed turn out the problem was outside the UITableView. What I didn't include was the fact that this UITableView is actually nested inside another UITableView. And that table's heightForRowAtIndex didn't quite have enough height so all touch events were being discarded (even tho the table didn't clip outside it's range).

Thanks all, sorry I didn't provide sufficient information from the get-go.