# Unresponsive screen on iPhone 5, iOS 6 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, screen, retina-display

I have added a Default-568h@2x.png to my app and it looks fine on Retina 4 inch simulator. However there is about 170 pixel area on the bottom of the screen where no response to tapping and/or touching. Do you have the same problem? Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is this happening just in your app or is it the same if you go to the "Home screen" of the simulator?  If it's just your app I'd suggest checking that your view is extending down into that area.

Comment: It was my app only. You have a good hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using MainWindow.nib, click the root VC and select "full screen at launch".

Alternatively, in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` `window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` (or `window.frame = window.screen.bounds`). This might be preferable if you have lots of nibs which you'd rather not touch (e.g. if you localize into 10 languages).

Comment: Thanks a lot! "window.frame = window.screen.bounds" worked perfectly.